# Que sentido tiene retornar useState hook de esta manera

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

estoy aprendiendo a utilizar context API de React y me encontre con una syntaxis que no termino de entender su finalidad

```
const useLoadingData = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  return {
    loading,
    setLoading,
  };
};

// Provider
export const OverviewProvider = ({ children }) => {
  //.    ......
  const { loading, setLoading } = useLoadingData(); // no entiendo la utilidad de esto

  const resetState = () => {
    setLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <OverviewContext.Provider
      value={{
        loading,
        setLoading,
        resetState
      }}
    >
```

No entiendo porque se crean funciones para retornar lo mismo, no seria igual crear dentro del provider una tupla con useState ?
Gracias

Comment: Quisieron usarlo como componente, pero no sé.. tampoco me convence mucho en realidad.

Answer (score 0):

La estructura de lo que estás viendo es un [custom Hook](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html), lo cuál permite reciclar lógica entre componentes... Lo extraño es que ese custom Hook que estás viendo no provee lógica, solo el estado, lo cuál no entiendo, porque es equivalente al hook `useState`. Te pongo esté ejemplo de la referencia que te pasé, en donde crean otro custom Hook pero tiene la función dispatch, que permite compartir la misma lógica entre componentes:

```
function useReducer(reducer, initialState) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

  function dispatch(action) {
    const nextState = reducer(state, action);
    setState(nextState);
  }

  return [state, dispatch];
}
```

Resalto también que es extraño que el hook no haga la deestructuración por medio de un array, como dice la documentación de React (y cómo funcionan los hooks por default como `useState`)... Lo hace por medio de un objeto, no sé cuales serán las intenciones del autor.

### Resumen

A final de cuentas tu tienes razón, es lo mismo que el `useState`, pareciese ser un `customHook` incompleto, perfectamente podrías hacer:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
```

En vez de:

```
const { loading, setLoading } = useLoadingData();
```

Se me ocurre que tal vez esto sea parte de un tutorial y crearon primero la estructura del custom hook y conforme avanza el tutorial van agregando lógica al mismo.